# Поиск необходимого селектора на динамической странице

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Имеется следующее: пишу автотест на прокликивание на демовой странице компании, в которой сейчас работаю.
Последовательность следующая: **автотест** заходит на сайт - вводит валидные логин и пароль - переходит по ссылке плиточного меню - выбирает предложенные заявления (**данные заявления появляются по нажатию кнопки со стрелкой вниз, не через некоторое время после загрузки страницы, а именно по нажатию кнопки**)
[image: Выбор заявления]

Написал код, по которому автотест доходит до этого места (выбор подтипа документа). и тут возник вопрос какую команду с селектором написать и какой прописать путь к этой кнопке.
В статическом состоянии класс данной кнопки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При динамическом состоянии класс кнопки меняется (то есть когда сам нажимаю на данную стрелку)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу оказать помощь в правильном написании автотеста, при котором он сам нажмет на данную стрелочку вниз

**Джава 11
Проект Мавен**

```
import dev.failsafe.internal.util.Assert;

import org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.C;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class TestOtpusk {

    @Test
    public void Test() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/User/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();

        driver.get("............................");

        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("..........");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("..........");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type=\"submit\"]")).click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("headInput")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Создать заявление")).click();
       


    }
```

Comment: С чего Вы взяли что он меняется? У Вас div.lookup-container, внутри которого div.lookup-button-container и, судя по картинке, так все и остается

Comment: Прошу прощения. Вставил не тот скриншот. Исправил

Comment: ну меняется и меняется, вы же его в коде вообще не используете насколько я вижу. Если уж вы пользуетесь ```ExpectedConditions```, то почему бы не ждать пока элемент на который вы хотите кликнуть станет кликабельным: ```ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable```, возможно решит проблему. Если нет, то можно кликать через ```JS``` это тоже часто помогает, если селениумный клик почему-то не хочет работать. Но в любом случае ваш скрин вообще не коррелирует с кодом

Comment: Может неправильно изложил суть вопроса. Мне получается нужно в автотесте прописать задачу чтобы тест нажал на эту стрелочку и после нее выбрал заявление на выбор.

Comment: отлично, что из этого не работает? опишите в вопросе, можете ссылку на страницу приложить, потому что сейчас не особо понятно

Comment: переписал вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вам всего лишь нужно подобрать селектор для данного элемента, то, что он слегка меняет `class` при наведении (скорее всего именно при наведении, а не клике, т.к. добавляется всё же 'hover') не должно нам помешать.

Например можно использовать xpath (это совершенно не обязательно, можно с тем же успехом использовать, например, `css` селекторы) для поиска вашего элемента:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'lookup-container')]"))
    .click()
```

Или же можно заметить, что есть `div` ниже, который не меняется при наведении на стрелку и пытаться нажать на него:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class = 'lookup-button-container')]"))
    .click()
```

ну или найти его, а потом просто подняться на уровень выше в наш первый элемент:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class = 'lookup-button-container')]/.."))
    .click()
```

Возможно селекторы придётся немного подправить, т.к. доступа к странице нет и протестировать не было возможности, но на первый взгляд они должны подойти.

**P.S.**
Иногда, часто по неясным причинам, селениумный клик не хочет работать (т.е. страница на него просто не реагирует), тогда можно попробовать кликать через `JS` это может помочь:

```
WebElement element = как-то нахождим нужный элемент;
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему немного другим способом.
По дереву нашел уникальный айди и после него начал спускаться до нужного класса.
Получилось так:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id=\"lkpDocumentCategory\"]>

[class=\"lookup-container\"]>[class=\"lookup-button-container\"]")).click();
```